# Importing Text from Table on Powerpoint to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm currently working on a code using VBA that will automatically import the text located in tables in Powerpoint slides to Excel either as text or as a table.

**The Slides looks like this:**

[image]

*** Updated Code as per TechnoDabbler assistance

```
    Public Sub CopySlideShapesText()

    ' Update the PowerPoint file name
    Const cPowerPointName = "test.pptx"

    Dim vPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim vPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim vSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim vPowerpointShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vRowCounter As Long

    ' Open the powerpoint presentation
    Set vPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set vPresentation = vPowerPoint.Presentations.Open(cPowerPointName)

    ' Write the slide info onto the active excel sheet
    Set vSheet = ActiveSheet

    ' Loop through each of the slides
    vRowCounter = 1
    For Each vSlide In vPresentation.Slides

        ' Loop through each shape on the slide
        For Each vPowerpointShape In vSlide.Shapes

            ' If shape isn't a table ... copy the text
            If Not vPowerpointShape.HasTable Then
                vPowerpointShape.Copy
                vSheet.Range("A" & vRowCounter) = vPowerpointShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                vRowCounter = vRowCounter + 1
            Else
                vPowerpointShape.Copy
                vSheet.Range("A" & vRowCounter).Select
                vSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                vRowCounter = vRowCounter + vPowerpointShape.Table.Rows.Count
            End If
        Next
    Next

    vPresentation.Close
    vPowerPoint.Quit

End Sub
```

***UPDATE***

Error showing

[image: Error Displaying]

[image: Line Item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Excelsson ... a table is a shape but needs to be treated a little differently; you can paste it in as an total entity ... or you could loop through the rows and columns within a shape (that contains a table). Here is an example of code that loops through all slides, and then all shapes on the slide, and if its a simple shape then it copies in the text, or if the shape contains a tables then it copies the total table in and proceeds to the next shape (taking into account the number of rows in the table):

```
Option Explicit

' ---> ADD REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT POWERPOINT OBJECT LIBRARY

Public Sub CopySlideShapesText()

    ' Update the PowerPoint file name
    Const cPowerPointName = "test.pptx"

    Dim vPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim vPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim vSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim vPowerpointShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vRowCounter As Long

    ' Open the powerpoint presentation
    Set vPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set vPresentation = vPowerPoint.Presentations.Open(cPowerPointName)

    ' Write the slide info onto the active excel sheet
    Set vSheet = ActiveSheet

    ' Loop through each of the slides
    vRowCounter = 1
    For Each vSlide In vPresentation.Slides

        ' Loop through each shape on the slide
        For Each vPowerpointShape In vSlide.Shapes

            ' If shape isn't a table ... copy the text
            If Not vPowerpointShape.HasTable Then
                If vPowerpointShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                    vPowerpointShape.Copy
                    vSheet.Range("A" & vRowCounter) = vPowerpointShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                    vRowCounter = vRowCounter + 1
                End If
            Else
                vPowerpointShape.Copy
                vSheet.Range("A" & vRowCounter).Select
                vSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                vRowCounter = vRowCounter + vPowerpointShape.Table.Rows.Count
            End If
        Next
    Next

    vPresentation.Close
    vPowerPoint.Quit

End Sub
```

An example of what it produces:

**Powerpoint Slides:**

[image: screen1]

**Excel Output:**

[image: screen2]

If you want to loop through the rows and columns of a table (or more correctly a shape that contains a table), you could adapt code from this answer: [Alert if empty cell found in power point tables and in which slide using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974889/alert-if-empty-cell-found-in-power-point-tables-and-in-which-slide-using-vba/56981343#56981343)

Cheers

Comment: Working great, however, it's getting stuck after loading the table of Slide 1, when closing PPT the error The specified Value is Out of Range is showing, any clue?  Also, how can this be modified to retrieve all slides and not just the first one, your code was definitely something!

Comment: @Excelsson - updated answer to loop through multiple slides, but still writing into the single active worksheet. Not sure what's generating the error ... you'll need to debug the specific line generating the error. Cheers.

Comment: I updated the question with the Error and the Line Item where it's showing @TechnoDabbler I appreciate it, must say there are 2 other objects in the slides, could that be it?

Comment: @Excelsson you might have shapes without text ... so adding in extra check (.hastext) into the code. Otherwise you'll have to debug the peculiarity of the object/shape triggering the error.

Comment: That did it, the .hastext definitely got it to work